# What sets of major collectable items are there in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Last time I played Skyrim I set my character the task of collecting all of the Dragon Masks. Because the masks are spread all over Skyrim and heavily guarded it made for a very enjoyable alternative to the normal quest lines.

Are there any other sets of major collectable items like the Dragon Masks?

Preferably I'm looking for items which are:

- Spread all over Skyrim (or at least a wide geographical area)
- Challenging to retrieve (guarded, or otherwise difficult to access)
- Related to give my character's task some sense of purpose
- Do not randomly spawn (I don't want to have to search an entire castle for something that may not be there)

I have all the DLC and am an experienced player if that helps.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'd love to get some more hours out of Skyrim.

Comment: There are the Stones of Barenziah. Though not difficult, they are a set

Comment: I have tried to collect one of each book (except spell books). It is indeed a challange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just some off of the top of my head:

Skyrim Collectables:

- Dragon Priest Masks
- Stones of Barenziah
- Thieves guild special items (sold to Delvin Mallory)
- All the Daedric Artifacts
- All the dragon shouts
- Dragon Claws

Dawnguard Collectables:

- The 5 [paragons](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Paragon)
- 4 more shouts

Dragonborn Collectables:

- The [Black Books](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Black_Books)
- Deathbrand Armor
- Ahzidal's Armor
- More dragon priest masks.
- 4 more shouts
- A few more dragon claws

Comment: There are also the Dragon Claws. They're unique, and often require entering the dungeon in question to obtain.

Comment: @FooBarrigno good point

Answer (score 3):

There are Glazed Candles, which will be hard to find since they seem to be a forgotten item in the community. (Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary near Falkreath and Radiant Raiments in Solitude are two places where I have found some)

There's also Ancient Traveller's Skull, Balbus' Spoon, Michaela's Flaggon, Ysgramors Soup Spoon, Aretino Family Heirloom, and the Dancer's Flute. (A few named misc items you can find in varying locations.)

According to UESPwiki, there are 1992 ruined books in the game; you could try finding them all.

Answer (score 1):

Ones I have:

1. Bugs in Jars
2. Thief Guild Collectables (One on each mission)
3. Every Armor Set (Heavy and Light)
4. All unique Armor sets
5. All weapons
6. Houses
7. Some Uniquely Named weapons (ie: Dravins bow)
8. All artifacts
9. All houses
10. All followers
11. All amulet of nine divine
12. Max skills
13. Max shouts and spells
14. All quest lines done
15. All stones
16. All locations cleared and discovered
17. All masks
18. The white vial
19. One Million Gold

Comment: I think you listed houses twice, unless you were trying to distinguish between the houses and Hearthfire's homesteads?

Answer (score 1):

You could also collect the treasure maps

Comment: This should just be a comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Roasted ox leg from the quest line of escaping Helgen and going to sovngarde after defeating the guard dude and then go inside and look on the tables all of the heros eat at and you will find the roasted ox leg as I did

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a "major collectible item" and definitely not part of a set...

Comment: Ok but this is like one of the funniest things I've ever read. I know this isn't reddit, but still...hilarious answer.